# Bitnami Redmine can fetch email, can't create ticket

Tags: redmine, bitnami

I'm trying to fetch emails from my IMAP server and create tickets with them, I tested the script as instructed [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineReceivingEmails) creating tickets in an abandoned project and it worked like a charm, but now when I changed only the project name in my script, it marks the emails as read in the mail server but no ticket is created.  I set the project to public and I even checked the `is_public` field in table `Projects` in MySQL.

My script to fetch emails looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh
cd /opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs 
bin/rake -f /opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=mail.my_domain.com username=support@my_domain.com password=my_pwd project=app-support unknown_user=create
```

Notice that my project name has two words, I have tried:

- project=app-support
- project="app-support"
- project=App-Support
- project="App-Support"
- project="App Support"
- project="app support"

Is there any extra configuration on the project that needs to be done? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  Just in case anybody runs into the same problem.  I checked `/opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/log/production.log` and I realized Category was marked as a required field.  I added that to the script and that was it.